# Как удалить Postman из Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, postman

Поставил давно Postman в Ubuntu, теперь хочу удалить. Как ставил - не помню. Postman доступен из HUD-меню. Postman сам по себе **работает как хром-приложение**

Пробовал такие способы, и они не работают:

- в HUD-меню нет "Удалить"
- `sudo whereis postman`, `sudo whereis Postman` - пусто
- после запуска делаю `ps aux | grep -i postman | grep -v grep` - пусто (так как хром-приложение)
- `cd /; sudo find -iname postman` выдал два каталога `~/.config/Postman` и `~/Postman`, я их зачистил, но Postman остался в HUD-меню и успешно из него запускается

Как найти и правильно удалить?

Comment: через `sudo` попробуйте запустить `whereis`

Comment: @MuckSon, спасибо, но так же пустой результат

Comment: `sudo find / -iname postman` попробуйте. Если вы его устанавливали, то он скорее всего в каких-то корневых папках лежит типа `/usr/`, чтобы там искать, нужно начинать искать из корня `/`, все это можно делать только через `sudo`.

Comment: @MuckSon - так же пусто, этот способ я уже пробовал

Comment: А вы уверены что удалили его из `~/Postman`?

Comment: @MuckSon, уверен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо зайти в Хром, управление расширениями `chrome://extensions/`

В самом низу показаны приложения на основе Хрома. Именно отсюда можно удалить приложение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]